# While automating Whatsapp my code types the message multiple times without sending it while it is supposed to type it once and send it in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, whatsapp

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

name = str(input("enter the name of the group:"))
msg = str(input("enter teh message:"))
count = int(input("enter the count:"))

input("enter anything after scanning the qr code")

user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title= "{}"]'.format(name))
user.click()

msg_box= driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3uMse')

for i in range(count):
    msg_box.send_keys(msg)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1JNuk')
    button.click()
```

and when i give it to write "lo" for 50 times it does this as given in the image

[image]

how can i click the send button everytime after typing the input

SOORY!!if the question is too messy im just a noob programmer!!

Comment: When you step through the code with a debugger, does it work? Does `driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1JNuk')` always find the correct button and does the click always work if you step through slowly? Or is that class name maybe randomly changing?

Answer (score 0):

if that send button click is not working ,you can try below options,

> Option 1-Instead of click on send button if we just press enter the
> message will send

```
 msg_box.send_keys(msg+ Keys.ENTER)
```

> Option 2- Assuming your xpath is correct,you also try to click on send button using javascriptexecutor

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1JNuk')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```